# Easing Effect scroll to div

Tags: javascript

i had this script used on my site but there's no easing effect on it can anyone tell me how to add easing effect on this script?

```
<script>

var scaffold = document.getElementById('scaffold');
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

menu.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
  if (e.detail.isSelected) {
    scrollToSection(e.detail.item.getAttribute('name'));
  }
});

function scrollToSection(id) {
  var section = document.getElementById(id);
  if (section) {
    scaffold.$.headerPanel.scroller.scrollTop = section.offsetTop, 500;
  }
}
```

Comment: No easy way to do that with pure Javascript. Use jQuery animate or CSS3 transition easings. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to use jQuery you can use its [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.